# Writing Binary Data As A String C#

Tags: c#, binary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a binary string representation to a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436398/convert-a-binary-string-representation-to-a-byte-array)

I have a string s = "010101010001..." of ones and zeros that I would like to write to a binary file.  How is this done?

Comment: Thank you, that is the answer I was looking for.  I did look through quite a few topics on this site - however, I mostly found going from Binary to String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the string every 8 characters and then convert it to a Byte with Convert.ToByte.