# C# textbox license key auto formatting

Tags: c#, regex

I'd like to provide users with a fancy license key textbox, that would insert the dashes.
The key is supposed to be 20 characters long ( 4 groups of 5 characters )

I tried using regex, first:

```
Regex.Replace( text, ".{5}", "$0-" );
```

that is a problem as the dash is inserted even when there's no following characters, e.g 
AAAAA-, that results in not being able to remove the dash as it's automatically re-inserted.

then I thought about telling the regex there should be a following character

```
Regex.Replace( text, "(.{5})(.)", "$1-$2" );
```

but that splits the key into group of 5-6-6...

Any ideas?

Comment: The way I've usually seen this is 4 text boxes, but when you fill up each one it *tabs* over to the next one automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead to avoid `-` to be added at the last. It matches each 5 digits of input string  from the first but not the last 5 digits.

```
.{5}(?!$)
```

Replacement string

```
$0-
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oS3pU4/2)

```
string str = "12345678909876543212";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @".{5}(?!$)", "$0-");
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

```
12345-67890-98765-43212
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/MtUvSG)

Answer (score 0):

```
 .{5}[^$]
```

Use this.This will not put a - at the end.

Replace by

```
  $0-
```

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/vY0rD6/3

Comment: it works only if you put any character inside the not char class which wasn't present in  the input string. `$` inside the char class matches a literal `$` symbol not the line end. see http://regex101.com/r/vY0rD6/4

Comment: yups missed it completely .

Answer (score 0):

A linq style method might be to your liking if you fancy a non-regex way...

This can be ran in LinqPad:

```
var sourceReg = "abcdeFGHIJ12345klmno";
var splitLength=5;

var regList = Enumerable.Range(0, sourceReg.Length/splitLength).Select(i => sourceReg.Substring(i*splitLength, splitLength));
regList.Dump("Registration List");

var regSeparated = string.Join("-", regList);
regSeparated.Dump("Registration with Separators");
```

Note: doesn't take into account reg codes that don't divide exactly.

See the method above plus others in a similar question:

[Add separator to string at every N characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932096/add-separator-to-string-at-every-n-characters)

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
string key = "12345678909876543212";
licenseBox.Text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(key, @".{5}(?!$)", "$0-");
```

"As Mentioned Above" - Should work fine.

And the following might also work for you.

**Code**

```
string key = "12345678909876543212";
licenseBox.Text = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}", key.Substring(0, 5), key.Substring(5, 5), key.Substring(10, 5), key.Substring(15, 5));
```

**Output**

```
12345-67890-98765-43212
```