# How to insert a space into a string, between every 4 characters?

Tags: c#, string

The string displays value as:

```
123456789012
```

I need it like:

```
1234 5678 9012
```

There should be space between every 4 characters in this string. How do I do that?

```
displaynum_lbl.Text = Regex.Replace(printClass.mynumber.ToString(), ".{4}", "$0");
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? At least a for loop?

Comment: Let's see some code that u have tried.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming that it's fine to work from right-to-left, this should do the trick:

```
displaynum_lbl.Text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(printClass.mynumber.ToString(), ".{4}", "$0 ");
```

You can find that and a good deal more information in other StackOverflow answers, example: [Add separator to string at every N characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932096/add-separator-to-string-at-every-n-characters)

Comment: this didn't work Jonathan.

Comment: Hmm..  I tested it out on my server and it seems to work.  Does it give an error?

Comment: I just edited it to put the full method in.  Let me know if that goes any better.

Comment: there is no error. out put didn't change. not shown even in debug.

Comment: As I mentioned in the other comment, make sure you include the space in the last string: "$0 ", not "$0".  The space is your separator, and could be replace by a comma or longer string if desired.

Answer (score 12):

```
        String abc = "123456789012";

        for (int i = 4; i <= abc.Length; i += 4)
        {
            abc = abc.Insert(i, " ");
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: this works....tested in VS 2013

Comment: Takes just one click to accept answer. Thanks....

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in LINQ:

```
var s = "123456789012";
var list = Enumerable
    .Range(0, s.Length/4)
    .Select(i => s.Substring(i*4, 4))
    .ToList();
var res = string.Join(" ", list);
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LZC2ZD)

Answer (score 1):

```
public string InsertSpaces(string s)
{
    char[] result = new char[s.Length + (s.Length / 4)];

    for (int i = 0, target = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        result[target++] = s[i];
        if (i & 3 == 3)
            result[target++] = ' ';
    }
    return new string(result);
}
```