# Convert string to debit card format

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I have a string like this

```
"6s49fw7eq7ews5th"
```

I am trying to format it like this

```
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX
```

How do I do this with `string.Format` ?

Comment: I feel like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932096/add-separator-to-string-at-every-n-characters) post might be helpfull to you. It doesn't use `String.Format` but instead it uses `String.Insert`.

Comment: Thanks . helpfull this post . i learn how do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another LINQ method. I use [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range) to minimise repeated code and magic numbers.

**Using [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876):**

```
string cardNumber = "1234567890123456";
IEnumerable<string> subStrings = Enumerable.Range(0, 4)
    .Select(n => cardNumber.Substring(n * 4, 4));

string result = String.Join("-", subStrings);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Run it [here](https://ideone.com/Bzypot) on ideone.com.

---

**Using [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d):**

```
string cardNumber = "1234567890123456";
string[] subStrings = Enumerable.Range(0, 4)
    .Select(n => cardNumber.Substring(n * 4, 4)).ToArray();

string result = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}", subStrings);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Run it [here](https://ideone.com/xId4jH) on ideone.com.

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple solution.

```
string t = "6s49fw7eq7ews5th";
string td = t.Substring(0, 4) + "-" + t.Substring(4, 4) + "-" + 
            t.Substring(8, 4) + "-" + t.Substring(12, 4);
```

or with insert

```
string td = t.Insert(4, "-").Insert(9, "-").Insert(14, "-");
```

or with split/join

```
string td = String.Join("-",Enumerable.Range(0, (int)(t.Length / 4d))
                        .Select(i => t.Substring(i * 4, 4)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution which is tested at my end:

```
string code = "1234567891011121";
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}", code.Substring(0, 4), code.Substring(4, 4), code.Substring(8, 4), code.Substring(12, 4)));
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`MoreLINQ`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) with [`Batch`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs) method like;

```
string s = "6s49fw7eq7ews5th";
var list = s.Batch(4, seq => new string(seq.ToArray()));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("-", list));
```

Prints

```
6s49-fw7e-q7ew-s5th
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Join` with `Enumerable.Select` overload:

```
string str = "6s49fw7eq7ews5th";
string newStr = String.Join("", str.Select((c, i) => i != 0 && i % 4 == 0 ? "-" + c.ToString() : c.ToString()));

Console.WriteLine(newStr); // 6s49-fw7e-q7ew-s5th
```