# What is the correct syntax of adding white space after specified number of characters using regex.replace()?

Tags: c#, string

I'm using `Regex.Replace` to add a *white space* after every `n`th character into a string. I want to give an int variable(number of characters) after which white space should be added but It seems *regular expression* is not properly written for int variable and hence syntax error arises.

```
 int num = 8;
    string text="abcdefghijklmnop"
    string result2 = Regex.Replace(text, ".{num}", "$0 "); //not working
```

> this syntax is working

```
 string result2 = Regex.Replace(text, ".{8}", "$0 ");
```

Comment: When you say "actual syntax", do you mean that's a working example? It's not clear to me what you mean by "regex.replace() is not accepting int and there is a syntax error" - could you edit your post to clarify that?

Comment: yes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932096/add-separator-to-string-at-every-n-characters

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions aren't parameterized in the way that you want, as far as I'm aware. Instead, you need to just build the pattern appropriately.

For *most* situations in modern C# I'd suggest using an interpolated string literal, which does work in this case, but requires the `{` and `}` to be doubled to avoid being treated as format specifiers. It may be more readable to just use string concatenation. So you can either use:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(text, ".{" + num + "}", "$0 ");
```

or if you're comfortable with `{` having different meanings in the same literal:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(text, $".{{{num}}}", "$0 ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you want, but you may build the regex pattern using string concatenation:

```
int num = Int32.Parse(text_num);
string regex = ".{" + num + "}";
string result2 = Regex.Replace(text, regex, "$0 ");
TextArea1_trim_id.InnerText = result2;
```

This answer says nothing regarding whether your regex pattern makes any sense or is correct.

Comment: Posted a few seconds before Jon Skeet.  Just saying :-)

Comment: He allowed for that to happen since he controls time-space continuum

Answer (score 1):

Alternative *Linq* solution (no *regular expressions*): we insert `" "` after each `num` characters (`c`)

```
  int num = 8;
  string text = "abcdefghijklmnop";

  // "abcdefgh ijklmnop " 
  string result2 = string.Concat(text
    .Select((c, i) => (i + 1) % num == 0 
       ? c.ToString() + " " 
       : c.ToString()));
```

If we don't want to add *trailing* spaces (and thus we want `"abcdefgh ijklmnop"`)

```
  string result2 = string.Concat(text
    .Select((c, i) => i < text.Length - 1 && (i + 1) % num == 0 
       ? c.ToString() + " " 
       : c.ToString()));
```