# How convert string like "00001111" into byte

Tags: c#

I want to convert string that have value like "00001111"
to `byte`

I tried this code for convert from byte to string:

```
byte b = 255;
string s = Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

This code works fine, but I need the opposite to convert from binary string back to a `byte`.

Comment: Your code seems to do - ``byte to string`` but your question is ``string to byte`` - do you need both or one of those?

Comment: [`Convert.ToByte("00001111",2);`](http://rextester.com/KVWO87894) ?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/a/10380166/6838730](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10380166/6838730) ?

Comment: I tried this code: ... and then what? What happened? Whats wrong?

Comment: @Wndrr: Nah that;s not the same question, there will defo be a dupe around though

Comment: i just want to convert from string to byte

Comment: the code is right and its to convert for byte to string but i want code to revers the function (string to byte)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some searching it seems there isn't an exact match for this question that I could find. The closest is [converting to a `byte[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436398/convert-a-binary-string-representation-to-a-byte-array) in which the suggested answers do include a solution to this question, but the code is more complicated than needed for just a single byte.

If you simply have an 8 character string you can use the [`Convert.ToByte()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y57wwkzk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method:

```
string input = "00001111";
byte output = Convert.ToByte(input, 2);
```

---

It is worth noting that you should validate your input to ensure it is a valid 8 character string before trying to convert it. You can actually have less than 8 characters and it will assume leading zeros, as long as you have at least 1 character, but you cannot have more than 8. Characters must be either `"0"` or `"1"`.

Though I guess it depends on how reliable your input data will be to determine if it needs validation.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the the standard library didn't have a built-in function, you could write one pretty easily:

```
var s = "00001111";
var n = 0d;

for(var i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{   
    var d = s[s.Length - 1 - i] == '0' ? 0 : 1;     
    n += (d * Math.Pow(2, i));
}

var b = (byte)(((int)n) & 0xFF);
```

To validate the input (which you will probably want to do in any case):

```
s.Length <= 8 && s.All(c => c == '0' || c == '1');
```

Comment: Does it not defeat the point of writing your own function if you end up using `Convert.ToByte()` as part of it? You would also probably want to validate null and empty strings too