# Create byte array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, upload

Is there a way to create a byte array from a file in JavaScript (or Typescript) that will be sent to a C# WebApi service, and consumable by the C# byte array method parameter?  If so, can you provide an example of the JavaScript?

I should mention, this is an Angular 4+ application that will be posting to the service.

I need to upload Word documents, PDFs and images to a C# service, and this is the way the C# service is currently built.  It expects a byte array of the file being uploaded.

This is the request object of the C# service:

```
[DataContract]
public class SaveAttachmentRequest : BaseRequest
{
    [RestUrlParameter(Mode = UrlParameterMode.Inline)]
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)] public AttachmentLookupInformation LookupInformation { get; set; } = new AttachmentLookupInformation();
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)] public byte[] Attachment { get; set; } = null;
}
```

And this is the AttachmentLookupInformation class:

```
[DataContract]
public class AttachmentLookupInformation
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)] public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)] public Guid LinkedToId { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
    ///<summary>Not including the path- just the file name and extension.</summary>
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)] public string FileName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)] public int FileSizeInBytes { get; set; } = 0;
    ///<summary>MIME type.</summary>
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)] public string ContentType { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)] public AttachmentCategories AttachmentCategory { get; set; } = AttachmentCategories.Unknown;
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)] public string DownloadUrl { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)] public string CreatedBy { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)] public DateTimeOffset CreatedTimestamp { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.MinValue;
}
```

This is so I can upload the file and additional data to the service.

EDIT: including failed Angular code that I used:

```
const lookupInfo = new AttachmentLookupInformation();
lookupInfo.Id = Helpers.emptyGuid;
lookupInfo.LinkedToId = this.contractId;
lookupInfo.AttachmentCategory = 10;

const request = new SaveAttachmentRequest();

const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function() {
  const buffer = reader.result;
  let binary = '';
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  const length = bytes.byteLength;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
  }

  request.Attachment = binary;
  lookupInfo.ContentType = files[0].type;
  lookupInfo.FileName = files[0].name;
  lookupInfo.FileSizeInBytes = length;
};
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(files[0]);
reader.onloadend = function() {
  request.LookupInformation = lookupInfo;

  console.log('request: ', request);

  that.contractsService
    .save(request, 'attachment/saveattachment')
    .subscribe(res => {
      if (res.Success) {
        console.log('upload response: ', res);
      }
    });

};
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data

Comment: @nvioli - I did try this days ago, but I couldn't get it to work, meaning that the service rejected my post with a 406, invalid input parameter.  I probably did something wrong, but not sure what.

Comment: That's the information you should put in your post, then. It's much easier for the community to help when given a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather thank asking for an end-to-end solution. If you think the problem is with your javascript code, then provide the javascript code you've written and detail the error you're getting.

Comment: @nvioli - You're right.  I just added the code that I tried that failed.  It's returning the 406 - Invalid input parameter error.

Comment: Note: this question's title really shouldn't be "create a byte array in JavaScript" - it looks like this is already being done.  Where the issue is, is getting the server-side to recognize that it's a `byte[]` and sending it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have:

```
that.contractsService
    .save(request, 'attachment/saveattachment')
```

But your class you're showing is `SaveAttachmentRequest`, with `public byte[] Attachment` inside that.  You don't have a function showing in your question called `saveattachment` inside a class called `attachment`, which is what should be processing the transferring of the data to the byte[], I would think, unless you're somehow just setting it directly into the parameter.  Assuming you have such an `attachment` class, it should be where you'd have an entry point called `saveattachment` that does all the work.  But say that it *is* failing because you are passing in your JS model and mapping it directly to the .NET one.  So then create a string parameter that can accept your binary string, then save it over to your `byte[]` one.

```
[DataMember(IsRequired = true)] public string strAttachment { get; set; } = null;
```

and in your JS,

```
request.Attachment = binary;
```

becomes

```
request.strAttachment = binary;
```

Then you'd need:

```
public class attachment : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public JsonResult saveattachment(SaveAttachmentRequest sar, AttachmentLookupInformation ali)
    {          
        //string bits = "000011110000001000";
        string bits = sar.strAttachment;
        int numOfBytes = (int)Math.Ceiling(bits.Length / 8m);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[numOfBytes];
        int chunkSize = 8;

        for (int i = 1; i <= numOfBytes; i++)
        {
            int startIndex = bits.Length - 8 * i;
            if (startIndex < 0)
            {
                chunkSize = 8 + startIndex;
                startIndex = 0;
            }
            bytes[numOfBytes - i] = Convert.ToByte(bits.Substring(startIndex, chunkSize), 2);
        }

        sar.attachment = bytes;

        // ... do your other stuff for saving your model objects to the DB
        // using Entity Framework's data context, etc.
    }
}
```

That's just one way of converting a binary string to byte[].  Plenty of other ways [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436398/convert-a-binary-string-representation-to-a-byte-array).

Or, have you tried just sending it as a string, making this:

```
[DataMember(IsRequired = true)] public byte[] Attachment { get; set; } = null;
```

turn into this:

```
[DataMember(IsRequired = true)] public string Attachment { get; set; } = null;
```

in the first place?

Answer (score -1):

In file type input change event you can get byte array. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556664/getting-byte-array-through-input-type-file) should help you.