# How to convert 0 and 1 string to byte[] in java?

Tags: java, huffman-code

I am trying to convert string of 0 and 1 to `byte[]` to save this in file, and in next step read this from the file and convert to string of 0 and 1. I don't know how to write `toByteArray(String input)`

Something like this:

```
String input = "011100101110001101000";
byte[] array = toByteArray(input);//how to do it
String output = "";

for(byte b : array) 
    outputString += Integer.toBinaryString(b);

System.out.println(output);// 011100101110001101000
```

Comment: Maybe, something I am doing wrong , but it's not working well becouse after convert to byte[], I can not convert agine to 0 and 1 string

Comment: To go the other way, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3436398/102937).

Comment: @RobertHarvey  where is other way in this post ?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3436456/102937).

Comment: 1.It's not Java. 2.What when binaryString.lenght() % 8 != 0 ?